# Find the closest matrix with equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

For given complex matrices $A$ and $B$, I want to find
\begin{align}
\min_{D_1,D_2} \|D_1 A D_2-B\|_F
\end{align}
where $D_1,D_2$ are diagonal matrices with each diagonal entry on the unit circle. What is the most relevant algorithm for this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a sleek direct solution to the problem, though the quadratic nature of both the objective and constraints give me pause. As a starting point, notice that if you fix either $D_1$ or $D_2$, you can optimize the other one by solving independent orthogonal procrustes problems for each diagonal entry; one computational approach is then to alternate fixing $D_1$ and finding $D_2$, and vice-versa.